# Does a type that implements copy get moved if possible?

Tags: rust

If you pass a type into a function that is not a pointer type and it implements Copy, does Rust copy it only if necessary?

Here is some specific code:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Data([u8; 2]);

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Buffer(Data);

fn do_something(id: Buffer) {
    println!("{}", id.0.0[0]);
}

fn create_buffer() -> Buffer {
   Buffer(Data([0x01, 0x01]))
}

fn main() {
    let buffer = create_buffer();

    // Since we don't use buffer again in this function, copy trait isn't necessary on Buffer.
    // But, "Buffer" does implement the Copy trait. Will Rust copy it anyway?
    do_something(buffer);
}
```

If rust does not copy it, are there rules to this behavior or is it entirely up to the compiler to decide? Can I rely on this not being copied?

What if I were to call do_something(buffer) twice? Does it copy twice, or move once and copy once? This requires the copy trait to even compile so I expect at least 1 copy.

```
do_something(buffer);
do_something(buffer);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

move and copy are solely type system concerns denoting whether the source can or can not still be used (by high-level code) after it has been used once[0]. In the lingo, it only defines [whether the type is affine (aka move, the default) or normal (`Copy`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system)

After typechecking, both result in the same actual operation: a memcopy (semantically), then the normal elision optimisations will work the same for both and may optimise away the actual copy.

So the answer would be "yes". At a codegen level, there really is no difference between Copy and non-Copy types as long as they are used in the same way. Do note that the elision optimisation may fail to trigger *in both cases*. In fact there are issues on the tracker (some closed and some not) where "move elision" fails to trigger, and a large on-stack non-Copy type gets copied around.

[0] I believe there is limited NRVO and plans for more in MIR / rustc itself, but the vast majority of the work is left to LLVM: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32966